# Monitor window (Screen capture)

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a c# wpf app in which I want a grid or rectangle to show the contents of a window in my application.  It should be like a monitor which constantly shows what happens in the other window (video is being played in in it).

Is there a good way to capture the screen or some other option?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [VisualBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx) class - that might be able to handle what you want. I don't know if it can handle cloning video but [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970263.aspx) shows it copying a static part of the screen.

Comment: Spot on, including video ! :D